# can a placeholder be set on the input in an ng-table?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Is there a way to set a placeholder on the `<input>` created in an ngTable?

As a second choice, is there another way to set an input to serve as the filter?

Changes to [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20141220020723/http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/23) would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: you can have headers the way you like.. look at example 18

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to continue to use the input generated by ng-table.  But I can see how to use another `<input>` as the filter model here: http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/webtech/web/pagination-and-sorting-of-data-table-using-angularjs/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit ng-table.js

Unminify ng-table.js (ie: http://jsbeautifier.org/) and after that in line 250 you can find

```
<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter()[name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" ,class="input-filter form-control"/>
```

add placeholder there ie :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter()[name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" placeholder="input {{name}}",class="input-filter form-control"/>
```

Please see here for working demo :

http://plnkr.co/edit/q0CMCb7evmZh1sflVV5f?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

To avoid editing the ng-table.js file you could add the following:

```
angular.module('ngTable').run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('ng-table/filters/text.html', '<input type="text" ng-model="params.filter()[name]" ng-if="filter==\'text\'" placeholder="{{name}}" class="input-filter form-control"/>');
}]);
```

This will create a cached copy of the template used in ng-tables 'text' filter   'ng-table/filters/text.html'.

Answer (score 2):

Add a new solution
inside ng-table html, do something like this,

```
<td filter="{ address: {id:'text',placeholder:'ADDRESS'}}">{{row.address}}</td>
```